# UIView not resizing correctly with UINavigationController in iOS 7

Tags: uiview, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

I encountered a strange behaviour of a view in an iOS 6.1 app which I tried ran with the iOS 7 beta 2 and on my iPhone.
This app has a UINaviagationController which works fine if I run it in the iOS 6.1 simulator. However, with the Xcode DP the bottom part of the view is cut off. See picture.
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I am drawing the box that you see as cut off on the bottom (self.frame.size.height) of the UIView which is managed by the navigation controller.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to share some code here.  What event is running when you size the box?  Are you using a NIB at all?  What is the parent of the UIView?  Are you using the older or newer auto size calculations?  Lots of information is relevant to this, and there isn't enough here to speculate on even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try subtracting the size of the box by the amount of the toolbar at the top. When using the self.frame.size.height, it will use the entire height as the location on the view, so when subtracting by the toolbar/navigation bar, it will raise that up just enough to fit the entire box onto the view

```
  //clearly not objc but its just to show you how to implement it
  boxLocation at (self.frame.size.height - (amount of toolbar/nav bar))
```

Hope this helps!